# How do I create an image button with text from XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create a simple image button that will read a XML file, take the data from a tag, and write it on the image button.
Because I am trying to change the title when a user changes the language.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

if By change language you mean user will change device language through setting , then write modify text in

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: no i will give the language option in my application and i want to map to xml file to read the tags

Comment: in the first page of the application the user will chose the language En ,Fr and then there will be labal on the image button it will read from XML file if the user choses En then it will read english tags